# Definition of convex and tangents

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

My calculus textbook states the definition of convex function $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ as the following

"Consider $f$ is differential in $(a,b)$. Then $f(x)$ is defined to be convex if for all tangent lines on $(a,b)$, $f(x)$ is above the tangent line."
i.e. $\forall{c}\in(a,b)$  $f(x)\geq f'(c)(x-c)+f(c)$ on $[a,b]$.

But I found out that convex functions are mostly defined similar to the Jensen inequality, as

"$f(x)$ is convex on $[a,b]$ if $\forall{x_1,x_2}$ $\forall{t\in[0,1]}$ $f(tx_1+(1-t)x_2)\leq tf(x_1)+(1-t)f(x_2)$"

If f is differential in the given interval, are these statements equivalent?
I've worked on $(2)\implies(1)$, but I have ran out of ideas on the converse.

Comment: See [Property 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Properties)